# Operation level authorization in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, security, row-level-security, authorization

I'm developing an analytics application that provides multiple levels of visualization of a data warehouse in a Postgres DB. One of its requirements is that different users should have different levels of access to the data. For example, some users should only extract metrics (`counts`, `avgs`, `sums`) from a particular table, while others could drill down the data to the level of columns.

Example:

```
employee table

 id    | name   | salary
-------+--------+--------+
     1 | josé   |  20000 
     2 | joão   |  80000 
     3 | tiago  |  60000 

user 1 (can drill down)
------
=> select name from employee where id = 1 
=> josé

user 2 (can read only aggregate data)
------
=> select avg(salary) from employee
=> 53333.3333333
=> select name from employee where id = 1 
=> ERROR
```

I don't think that any RDBMS would provide that natively. But I wondered if there is any tool that could help me accomplish this authorization level without having to hard code it at the application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with views.  The columns of the view must be given names, they can't be specified in the functional form.

```
create view employee_agg as select count(*), avg(salary) from employee;
grant SELECT ON employee_agg TO user2;
```

Now as user2:

```
select * from employee;
ERROR:  permission denied for table employee

select * from employee_agg;
 count |         avg         
-------+---------------------
     3 | 53,333.333333333336
```

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in mechanism Row Security Policies. [enter link description here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-rowsecurity.html)